# Lambda function to shutdown RDS not working - NameError: name 'client' is not defined

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-rds

I am using the below Lambda function but keep getting errors. I was able to use the function at the *bottom* of this page via Pycharm conducting some tests so was expecting this to work in Lambda. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import boto3

def handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('rds')

response = client.stop_db_instance(
    DBInstanceIdentifier='dev-mysql-rds'
)
```

> Response: {   "errorMessage": "name 'client' is not defined",
> "errorType": "NameError",   "stackTrace": [
> "  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 234, in load_module\n    return load_source(name, filename, file)\n",
> "  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source\n    module = _load(spec)\n",
> "  File "", line 702, in _load\n",
> "  File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked\n",
> "  File "", line 783, in exec_module\n",
> "  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
> "  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 6, in \n    response = client.stop_db_instance(\n"   ] }
>
> Request ID: "7fd994c0-799f-44a2-b93f-a437fee740af"
>
> Function logs: START RequestId: 7fd994c0-799f-44a2-b93f-a437fee740af
> Version: $LATEST [ERROR] NameError: name 'client' is not defined
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
>     return load_source(name, filename, file)   File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
>     module = _load(spec)   File "", line 702, in _load   File "", line 671, in
> _load_unlocked   File "", line 783, in exec_module   File "", line 219,
> in _call_with_frames_removed   File "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
> line 6, in 
>     response = client.stop_db_instance(END RequestId: 7fd994c0-799f-44a2-b93f-a437fee740af REPORT RequestId:
> 7fd994c0-799f-44a2-b93f-a437fee740af  Duration: 352.02 ms Billed
> Duration: 353 ms  Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 22 MB   Unknown
> application error occurred

**The below function works via Pycharm.**

```
import boto3
rds = boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='dev')
client = boto3.client('rds')

response = client.stop_db_instance(
    DBInstanceIdentifier='dev-mysql-rds'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

@Magitrek and @John Rotenstein
Thank you for your help. I managed to get it working with the below script in Lambda.
I had to use the lambda_handler because the originally posted handler did not work.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('rds')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    response = client.stop_db_instance(
        DBInstanceIdentifier='dev-mysql-rds'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the code is imported before `handler()` is executed, `client.stop_db_instance()` is executed before AWS lambda executes `handler()`, and outside of the scope of the handler function, so client is undefined. If you move that function call inside of the handler it should work.

Comment: Translation: The `response = ...` line should be _indented_ within the `def`, rather than being at the _same_ indent level as the `def`. That's how Python knows that it is part of the function.